# Does $f_n\longrightarrow f$ with respect to the $1$-norm $\parallel g\parallel_1 = \int_0^2\mid g(x)\mid dx$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

Consider $f_n:[0,2]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f_n(x)=\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l 1}
     nx, & \quad 0\leq x<1/n;\\
     2-nx, & \quad 1/n \leq x < 2/n;\\
     0, & \quad \text{otherwise}.
   \end{array} \right.$$

Does $f_n\longrightarrow f$ with respect to the $1$-norm $\parallel g\parallel_1 = \int_0^2\mid g(x)\mid dx$?

$f(x)=lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$.

To determine the pointwise limit...

Given $x>0$, choose $N>\frac{2}{x}$.

Then $f_n(x)=0$ for $n>N$.

For $x=0$, $f_n(x)=0$, so $f(x)=lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,2]$.

Have I determined the pointwise limit correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you determined the pointwised limit?

Comment: Sorry I realise the question is missing some vital pieces of information, I shall re-edit it...

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310499/analysis-convergence#comment67244).

Comment: Yes, you have correctly determined the pointwise limit to be the zero-function.

Answer (score 1):

What you showed is that $f_n$ converges almost everywhere (i.e. pointwise) to $0$. But $L^1$ and a.e. convergences do not necessarily imply each other. It is true though that if $f_n$ converges in $L^1$ and almost everywhere, then the limits must coincide (almost everywhere, of course).

So, going back to your question, it remains to check whether $f_n$ converges to $0$ in $L^1$, i.e. if $\|f_n\|_1\rightarrow 0$ as $n\to\infty$.
$$
  \|f_n\|_1
=
  \int_{(0,\frac 1n)}
    \hspace{-16pt}
    |nx| \,{\rm d}x
  +
  \int_{(\frac 1n,\frac 2n)}
    \hspace{-16pt}
    |2-nx| \,{\rm d}x
=
  \frac{1}{2n}
  +
  \frac{1}{2n}
$$
which goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. Therefore $f_n$ converges almost everywhere **and in** $L^1$ to $f=0$.

Comment: Thank you, would I be correct in saying that $f_n\nrightarrow f$ uniformly because $\parallel f_n\parallel_{\infty}=n\nrightarrow 0$ as $n\longrightarrow\infty$?

Comment: @Levi $\Vert f_n\Vert_\infty=1$ for each $n$. So, $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly to the zero function.

Comment: Yep, @DavidMitra is right in saying $\|f_n\|_\infty=1$... Be that as it may, $f_n$ does **not** converge uniformly.